# Pandas merge csv base on columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

Hi I know this has been answered before, but i am getting weird result those solutions. So would appreciate an explanation on what's wrong with my approach.

I have 2 csv files

#### f1

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,2,3
3,3,3
```

#### f2

```
C,D,F
3,3,1
1,1,1
```

I am trying to merge them.
Simple

```
f = pd.merge(left=f1, right=f2, how='outer', on='C')
```

But the merge result instead of giving expected table as

```
A,B,C,D,F
1,2,3,3,1
1,2,3,3,1
3,3,3,3,1
```

I am getting result  as:

```
A,B,C,D,F
1,2,3
1,2,3
3,3,3
,,3,3,1
,,1,1,1
```

Not sure why i am getting this.

I am not dealing this exact data. I reading this data from csv files as

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols=[colnames])
```

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
f2 = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv', usecols=[colnames])
f1 = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv', usecols=[colnames])
f = pd.merge(left=f1, right=f2, how='left', on='MergeCol')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your solution. You want to do a left join instead of outer:

```
import pandas as pd
f1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3], 'B':[2,2,3], 'C':[3,3,3]})
f2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':[3,1], 'D':[3,1], 'F':[1,1]})
f = f1.merge(f2, how='left', on='C')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  F
0  1  2  3  3  1
1  1  2  3  3  1
2  3  3  3  3  1
```

If you want to write back into a csv, just do:

```
f.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. I guess the issue is with the way i am reading csv files as when i run my code for file, i am still getting the same result. It seems `pd.read_csv('filename1.csv', usecols=[colnames])` is not creating proper dataframe.

Comment: @RajatVij Hmmm... looking at your edited code, you're passing `[colnames]` for both of your dataframe creation. That will essentially pull the same columns from both CSV files. In addition, if `colnames` is already a list, you don't need the square brackets. Also, if you're joining by `MergeCol`, then I'm assuming `MergeCol` is a column name that exists in both of your dataframes.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote colname for the sake of readability. I am passing values like `['name','date'..]`. And yes MergeCol is there in both csv files that have common values. There are multiple columns with same names that needs to be repeated, but the common data is in MergeCol.

Comment: Sigh, I just checked, My values for MergeCol are integers in csv, so in one of the files its coming as 12.0 and in another its coming as 12

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just casted it to string and used that to get this done. It was converting int to float as column had some NaN values. Will update post later.